# Why are my Brush options in Illustrator disabled?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a new calligraphic brush in Illustrator when I noticed alot of the options are disabled can anyone tell me why this is disabled and if it's possible for me to enable them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The brush dynamic options are only available if you have a **[drawing tablet](http://www.wacom.com/en-us/discover/draw)** connected to the system.

In some instances, even some drawing tablets may not make the options available. Adobe only *really* tests applications for Wacom tablets. They may do some cursory examination with tablets from other manufactures, but they primarily focus bug-squashing on Wacom tablets.